# fundamental group of the complement of a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

This should be a quick question. I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book. At page 46, in the example of computing the fundamental group of the complement in $\mathbb{R^3}$ of a single circle, he says the point inside $S^2$ and not in the circle can be pushed away from the circle towards $S^2$ or the diameter, which I don't understand. I understand the case where the point is outside $S^2$ deformation retract onto $S^2$ .Can anyone please explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Uh.. draw a picture to see , every point $x\in \mathbb R^3-S^2$ can be jointed by a straight segment with initial point x and terminal point y ( y is on the $S^1 \text {V}S^1$) [Really , I don't know how to explain it through words]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems an example where the natural solution uses  *the fundamental groupoid on two base points*, and groupoid methods, see the books [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) (first edition, differently named,   1968) and
[Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html) (first published, 1971). See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one

We can represent  $\mathbb R^3\setminus S^1 $ as the union  $U \cup V$ whose intersection $W$ is the plane through the circle, 
but without the circle. Then $U,V$ are contractible.  Since  $W$ is the union of two  components, choose  base points $x,y$, one  in each component, and let $P=\{x,y\}$.

We then have a  pushout, not of  the usual groups, but of **groupoids**:

$$ \matrix{\pi_1(W,P) & \to & \pi_1(V,P) \cr
\downarrow && \downarrow \cr 
\pi_1(V,P) & \to & \pi_1(X,P)} $$
This is now a standard  situation for the algebra of groupoids, which enables one to show that $\pi_1(X,x)$, and also $\pi_1(X,y)$, is isomorphic to  the integers. See also the paper [Brouwer](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brouwer-cor-fin.pdf).

This type of method also works for the fundamental group of the complement of a knot or graph in $\mathbb R^3$ - see again Topology and Groupoids, section 9.1.