# The fundamental group of the complement of a circle in 3D-space.

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is a fundamental group of $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ ? Here is my thinking:  Instead of looking $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$  I looked over $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus S^1$. In that $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus S^1$ is split into two components one is inside the circle and another one is outside the circle... A component inside the circle is simply connected and the fundamental group inside the circle is trivial and what about the fundamental group outside the circle?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question a bit. TeX, a more descriptive title, sentences beginning with an upper case letter, the works :-)

Comment: The outer component of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S^1$ is homeomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ and it's fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$. Concerning $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^1$, I suppose that classes of loops will differ in the winding number around the circle, and the fundamental group will again be $\mathbb{Z}$. Hope that someone will prove or disprove it :)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the answer may depend on exactly how the removed $S^1$ is located in 3-space? Van Kampen is your friend (and there may be other techniques as well). For example, if that $S^1$ is the unit circle of a plane in 3-space you get the answer given by lisyarus. If that $S^1$ actually is the trefoil knot you get something else (IIRC with the same abelianization).

Comment: is that correct i'm taking a open sets U=(R^3-S^1)-a and V=(R^3-s^1)-b where a,b are distinct and U intersect V to be (R^3-S^1)-a-b

Comment: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118477/fundamental-group-of-the-complement-of-a-circle?rq=1  .

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885356/11619) we have one way of seeing that the answer depends on the embedding of $S^1$. When the removed part is a trefoil (itself homeomorphic to $S^1$) the fundamental group is non-abelian.

Answer (score 1):

$R^3 - S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$.Hence $\pi_1(R^3 -S^1) = Z.$

Comment: How?  Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $S^1$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the trivial way, the homotopy class of every path in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ just depends on the winding number of the path around the circle (we can think to every path as a sequence of tight coils around a ring), hence:
$$\pi^1\left(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1\right)=\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: What's the non-trivial way of embedding $S^1$ in to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Bob: by *trivial* here I mean $$S^1\simeq\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1, z=0\}$$ but any change of coordinates would do the job just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

The graduate student math gave a very deep answer. But he gives no proof.

After I searched google I found an explanation: $S^3$ is union of two solid tori glued on boundries. Since $S^1$ is deformation reteract of solid tori, $\Bbb R^3 - S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to a solid tori minus a point inside.

But, solid tori minus a point inside is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$. I think, we can see this by expanding the point and squeezing the rest.